# Lazy load inner imports with webpack react

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4

Is it possible to lazy load all inner imports with react and webpack?

For ex:
File A -> having 2 imports A1 and A2 out of which A1 is lazy loaded with split code chunks. here A1 having inner A11, A12, A13 imports.

So is it possible to lazy load that with a split chunk?

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to split the code such that all A11, A12, A13, and A2 are separated into their own chunks?

Comment: I guess OP wants to lazy load A1 and its internal dependencies while having a normal loading for A2

Comment: Is this [this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) any help?

Comment: Yes, As A1 is already lazy loading, is it possible to lazy load all internal imports?